# Universal Link doesn't work on iOS

Tags: ios, hyperlink, universal, ios-universal-links

I am setting the iOS Universal Link support to my app following many tutorials (Branch.io, cordova universal link plugin, ...) and the official documentation but it doesn't work.
Here the steps I followed:

- Enable the Associated Domains service in the developper panel
- Enable the Associated Domains in the Xcode project file
- Add `applinks:app.mydomain.com` to my Capabilities
- Create the apple-app-site-association with the content below
- Upload the apple-app-site-association to the root of my web server
- Set the content mime to "application/pkcs7-mime"
- Verify it is accessible by the link: https://app.mydomain.com/apple-app-site-association
- Verify the https certificate is valid
- Verify the robots.txt enable the crawler for all the paths

My application pass the test on https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com/ when I check "Allow unencrypted AASA files" (my apple-app-site-association is not signed). My app pass the test on the Apple verificator : https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/

When I click on the url https://app.mydomain.com/m/link?token=aaaa from a mail in Safari on my iPhone I'm not redirected and the content of the page is displayed.

Comment: Does it work when you open the link from Messages, Mail (as in Mail app), or WhatsApp?

Comment: For a mysterious reason, now it works but it asks to the user to choose between to open the app store or to open the link in safari. Is it normal ?

Comment: That is not normal...I've never run into a message like that before. Is there a particular reason you're wanting to implement all of this yourself instead of using one of the pre-built deep linking platforms?

Comment: Now it doesn't work anymore... I didn't change anything since the time it worked.
@AlexBauer What do you mean by "the pre-built deep linking platforms" ?

Comment: Make sure you haven't [disabled them accidentally](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#universal-links-can-be-disabled-unfortunately). Most apps (Pinterest, Airbnb, Tinder, Instacart, HotelTonight, etc.) don't try to implement deep links on their own. They use a service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) to handle the technical details.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling your app? Your app checks the apple-app-site-association on install only, so if you've updated the location it will not check again by itself. If you view the device's console log (Window->Devices) you may notice an error with apple-app-site-association. Finally, make sure you're testing on an actual device, it won't work on simulator.